# Strange behaviour from special keyboard keys

Tags: linux-mint, usb, keyboard

> **OS: Linux Mint 13 Maya - MATE**

So, I had a new keyboard through today and there is something strange going on.

The following keys are identified as the Shift key.

> LEFT SHIFT
>
> RIGHT SHIFT
>
> LEFT CONTROL
>
> RIGHT CONTROL
>
> WINDOWS KEY ( SUPER )
>
> LEFT ALT
>
> RIGHT ALT

That's a lot of keys...

So these keys not only do the same as the shift key but they are also identified as the shift key,
I mean in Javascript the `event.keyCodes` are all 16 and they are also have identical info and key codes in `xev`.

I thought at one point it could be the keyboard, so I tried it in a separate machine running windows 7 and it worked fine. I then thought it
was the computer, so I pressed <kbd>E</kbd> on the GRUB menu screen and the control keys were working
fine there so it's got to be something to do with mint, the problem only occurs when mint boots to the login screen everything before that is fine.

I'm not sure what the problem is, at first I thought I would be able to do something to manually set the keys, but it turns out they are all identified as the same key so if I change one, then surely they'll all
change.

In the keyboard settings it's default

English (UK)

Generic 105-key. (Intl) PC

Comment: Is this specific to Mate? Do the keys work if you run a Gnome session or any other desktop environment? Is the keyboard actually a UK keyboard (the `@` should be just above the enter key)?  Do the keys work if you're at a text-console (hit Ctrl+Alt+F2 to drop to a tty and test, then Ctrl+Alt+F8 to return)? If you can't drop to a tty because of the Ctrl key, try booting into rescue mode an see if they work there. What is the keyboard make and model?

Comment: Since the keyboard works normally on Windows, it is probably not the keyboard, but you could try another keyboard.  This page might help, http://helpsite.org/change-language-keyboard-and-users-in-linux/, also check this, http://superuser.com/questions/377108/keyboard-configuration-file